# Different representations of Appell hypergeometric series

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

The (first) Appell series:

$$F(a; b_1, b_2; c \mid z_1, z_2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n}{(c)_n} \sum_{n_1+n_2=n} (b_1)_{n_1} (b_2)_{n_2} \, \frac{z^{n_1}}{n_1!} \frac{z^{n_2}}{n_2!}$$

can be written in integral from in two ways:

$$F(a; b_1, b_2; c \mid z_1, z_2) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(c-a)} \int_0^1 d t \, \frac{t^{a-1} (1-t)^{c-a-1}}{(1-z_1 t)^{b_1} (1-z_2 t)^{b_2}}$$

(due to Erdelyi) and:

$$F(a; b_1, b_2; c \mid z_1, z_2) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b_1) \Gamma(b_2) \Gamma(c-b_1-b_1)} \iint_{\triangle} d u_1 \, d u_2 \, \frac{u_1{}^{b_1-1} u_2{}^{b_2-1} (1-u_1-u_2)^{c-b_1-b_2-1}}{(1-z_1 u_1 - z_2 u_2)^{a}}$$

where $\triangle = \{0 \leq u_1, u_2 \leq 1 : 0 \leq u_1 + u_2 \leq 1\}$ (due to Bailey).

My question is what manipulations are necessary in order to express one of the integrals into the other one?

Comment: It seems to me that the equivalence must be a case of the Gauss Divergence Theorem.  If you are still interested I can probably compute it with some program; in detail.   Doesn't look neat though.  BTW: you seem to have left the subscripts off in $z^{n_{1}}z^{n_{2}}$

Comment: Also In the third formula I think one of the lower $b_1$'s in the pre-factor denominator should be $b_2$.

Comment: @rrogers  $$ F(a; b_1, b_2; c \mid z_1, z_2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n}{(c)_n} \sum_{n_1+n_2=n} (b_1)_{n_1} (b_2)_{n_2} \, \frac{z^{n_1}}{n_1!} \frac{z^{n_2}}{n_2!}$$ is defined for $|z_1|<1$ and $|z_2|<1$, right?  And How about this $$ F(a; b_1, b_2; c \mid z_1, z_2) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(c-a)} \int_0^1 d t \, \frac{t^{a-1} (1-t)^{c-a-1}}{(1-z_1 t)^{b_1} (1-z_2 t)^{b_2}}?$$ According to [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series) the validity condition is $R(c)>R(a)>0$.

Comment: @user3321  Are you really interested in a proof of the integral representations, the limits, or actually a transformation of the integrands?  Lucy Slater "Generalized Hypergeometric Functions" section 8.2 has the integral proofs in her/his, usual, masterful way; a great admirer here.   The proof is "elementary".  I can probably do direct integrand conversion but one would think Green's function or conformal transforms are indicated/better.  The later would seem to be more general and useful.  But I will reproduce Slater's proof for the StackExchange record if anyone is interested.

Comment: @rrogers Thank you for your comment. According to [Bezrodnykh](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652469.2017.1402017) this equation $$ F(a; b_1, b_2; c \mid z_1, z_2) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(c-a)} \int_0^1 d t \, \frac{t^{a-1} (1-t)^{c-a-1}}{(1-z_1 t)^{b_1} (1-z_2 t)^{b_2}}$$ is defined for $Re~ b>0 , Re (c-b)>0$, and $z~\epsilon~ |arg(1-z_i)|<\pi$, see the eq. 5.23. Wikipedia does not mention that.

Comment: $ Re b>0,Re(c−b)>0$ ?  In any case, Slater's proof uses a simple negative binomial expansion for b_x >0.  Superficially I don't see why that's necessary but <0 might integrate to a different function.  Although the series converges for all z_x <1 so I think the restriction might be bogus.  They are expanded to generate the series in z_x, m,n.  With the beta function as additional coefficients by Integration. In DLMF  the Beta description requires Re(a+m+n) and Re(c-a) >0.  Since the series is convergent for z_x <1 , c != -Z^+ ,I am not sure that even this restriction is justified.

Comment: I can't get acces to Bezrodnykh ; could you point to a free location?

Comment: @user3321 I just left two comments and neglected to point to you; and, of course, I didn't realize it until the silly 5 minute limit timed out.   Perhaps we could move this to the answer section; although it's a little off topic; or a workspace?

Comment: @user3321 In fact examining the defining series I am pretty sure I can directly extract the Beta function.  Leaving a simple Taylor series with the Beta function as a coefficient (and misc debris).  Sometimes going backwards is simpler.

Comment: @rrogers My doubt was whether the validity condition of  $$F(a; b_1, b_2; c \mid z_1, z_2) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(c-a)} \int_0^1 d t \, \frac{t^{a-1} (1-t)^{c-a-1}}{(1-z_1 t)^{b_1} (1-z_2 t)^{b_2}}$$ was only $ \text{Re} c > \text{Re}a$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series#Integral_representations).But according to Bezrodnykh (\text{\sout{$Sci-Hub$}}), the real condition is $R(c)>R(a)>0$, and $z~\epsilon~ |arg(1-z_i)|<\pi$.

Comment: @rrogers An interesting question about this function is being discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172425/error-in-integral-representation-of-appells-series)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76925/discussion-between-rrogers-and-user3321).